# On the iPhone, what would be the locale identifier for forcing US english representations of numbers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, locale

In particular I want to guarantee that the formatting of a number uses , (commmas) for separating digits regardless of the current locale of the device.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numFormatter setLocal:@"??????"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The U.S. uses a period as a decimal separator.  I assume you mean that you want to use a comma as a grouping separator.

You don't need to set the locale for this in your NSNumberFormatter, you can set both directly using code like the following:

```
[numFormatter setGroupingSeparator:","];
[numFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numFormatter setDecimalSeparator:"."];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried "en-US" ?